# There is some error in my flutter program

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Load Settings
Cannot load settings from file 'E:\Flutter_projects\imagepicker_app\imagepickerapp.iml': ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
                Message: Content is not allowed in prolog.
                Please correct the file content
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a file that is not anymore in your project or you've imported it wrong.

Try to run *Flutter Clean*